# xcode xcworkspace open without tools or Navigator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just oen the xcode "xcworkspace" it's open directly to the small screen without any tools or bars how can i back to the normal workspace ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below option may be it will work

Right-click on the toolbar area beside your project title, i think you can see 'Show Toolbar' option & click it.

On the far right of this toolbar, click the leftmost 'Show Navigator' button in the group of three 'View' icons.

This should present your project in the navigator on the left for you to access.

Comment: it's open new tap with same lock

Comment: You can go via View -> Show toolbar